# ionic angularx-qr code template parse error

Tags: ionic3, qr-code

After

```
npm install angularx-qrcode --save
```

import QRCode Module on app.module.ts

```
import { QRCodeModule } from 'angularx-qrcode';
@NgModule({
 imports: [
    QRCodeModule,
 ]
})
```

and add this line on html

```
<qrcode [qrdata]="myAngularxQrCode" [size]="256" [level]="'M'"></qrcode>
```

i Got this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'qrdata' since it isn't a known property of 'qrcode'
```

Ionic Info:

cli packages: (C:\Users\800079\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v6.10.0
npm  : 6.1.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue with your code is `qrdata` is not identified as a property of `qrcode` . This usually happens when you import the library to root module and you try to use it in a component that is declared in a different module. Make sure you have imported   `import { QRCodeModule } from 'angularx-qrcode';` to the module where your component is declared.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Did you forget to initialize the variable? Please try if you encounter the issue as well, when you don't use a variable but a string in [qrdata]:

```
<qrcode [qrdata]="'A simple string'" [size]="256" [level]="'M'"></qrcode>
```

**Original Post:**
I'm the author of [angularx-qrcode](https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode) you mentioned.

I prepared a working demo-app for angular5 & angular6. The implementation for angular itself and ionic are the same. You can clone the entire app here and have a look at the code:

https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode-sample-app

The master-branch contains the angular6 version, while the angular5 version is in the angular5-branch.

HTH